# How to use lxc exc to issue multiple commands as specific user

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, nvm, lxc

My goal is to execute two commands in a specific folder as ubuntu from outside of it's lxc container.

I've tried a couple of things but I figured this example is the closest I have to working.

If I run

```
root@host$  lxc exec my-containter -- sudo --login --user ubuntu eval "cd /home/ubuntu/mydir && pwd && whoami && env && npm install && echo done"
```

I get an npm install error that can't find some module, but it looks like I'm the right user

However if I manually do it as two steps it does work... but I'm trying to put this in a bash script, so that I can keep doing operations on the host, so I think I need it as one.

```
root@host$  lxc exec my-containter -- sudo --login --user ubuntu 
ubuntu@my-container$  eval "cd /home/ubuntu/mydir && pwd && whoami && env && npm install && echo done";
```

I discovered that my PATH environment variable is different in these two situations, the one that is failing is missing a specific path for nvm/npm. I tried exporting it during the eval command, but it seems like the resources available to me have already been found? What could I do to make the PATH variable populate the same way in the single line scenario?

PATH from 1-line (non-interactive)

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

PATH from 2-lines (interactive)

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

I've also noticed this nvm code at the bottom on my .bashrc file. From what I've read it sounds like the .bashrc file only gets executed in interactive mode.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: Try `lxc exec my-containter -- sudo --login --user ubuntu sh -lc "cd /home/ubuntu/mydir && pwd && whoami && npm install && echo done"`. If that doesn't work instead of `sh` try with `bash`

Comment: my PATH variable is still different testing that with sh and bash.
I test the PATH contents by checking with
 "&& env"
I assume the PATH (and other variables) are set with NVM, but I'm not sure how they're set.

Comment: Can you show both the `env` results? The `-l` flag I had added make sure that the profile is also loaded

Comment: I've noticed NVM has lines at the bottom of the bashrc file, and it sounds like this file doesn't get run when running in non-interactive mode. I'll update the main question with that and the PATH

Comment: I think I figured it out. Please use `bash -ilc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below command should do the job for you

```sh
lxc exec my-containter -- sudo --login --user ubuntu bash -ilc "cd /home/ubuntu/mydir && pwd && whoami && npm install && echo done"
```

The `.bashrc` file has below at the top

```sh
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
```

This code prevents the rest of the part of `.bashrc` to be executed in case of a non-interactive bash. So to make it interactive you should add the `-i` flag

Comment: perfect. that did the trick, much better than the path I was going down: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1718